# Ubuntu 17 no redirection to WiFi login page (only in some networks)

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 17.04, intel-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 17 on a Lenovo Ideapad 700 and I'm having some troubles connecting to only some public WiFi networks. The problem is, after connecting to the hotel's WiFi, Firefox won't redirect me to the login page. But in my office's WiFi network it perfectly redirects to login page without any issues.

Please note that the hotel's WiFi network work with other devices. Also I tried to enter random URLs and IPs after googling and nothing seems to work.

Any help is much appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot log in to public open Wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826998/cannot-log-in-to-public-open-wifi-connection)

Comment: This might interest you: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/ubuntu-17-10-work-captive-portal-wifi

Comment: When it happens to me, I request a non-https url. This should not be an url like google.com which will redirect you to the https version, because your browser will cache the redirection. You can try something like http://web.mit.edu/

Comment: @pim this is become less and less common, especially with the push by Google and others (e.g. the LetsEncrypt initiative) to make *all* pages secure

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 (Unity) I ran `route -n` where the first "Destination" was `0.0.0.0` and the "Gateway" was `172.31.0.1`. I could ping the gateway IP (`ping 172.31.0.1`), but not public ones like Google's `8.8.8.8`.

Captive portal was working on my android phone so I could connect there and see which URL I was being redirected to in my mobile browser. I used this to edit my hosts file in order to connect the IP to this domain: `sudo vi /etc/hosts` and added a new entry like:

```
172.31.0.1 gialto.wifi/hotspot/novotelmedellinguest
```

Then in the internet settings in the upper right of the desktop I unticked "enable networking" and then reticked it. From there I could put the full http://gialto.wifi/hotspot/novotelmedellinguest URL into my browser and enter my credentials / accept their terms.