# Wifi connects on Windows but not Linux

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, connman

I have a dual boot linux system that is running ubuntu 22.04 and windows 10.  I am able to connect to the public wifi and get the lading page where i have to accept the rules and it logs me right in.  This has been working for years, still does no problem.  I have a laptop that I have Ubuntu 22.04 on.  I cannot connect to the network,  It tries but after 60 secs it just says cannot connect.  i have tried this with other flavors of linux (Arch, Fedora) all the same issue.  I can connect fine to most if not all other networks, just not this one.  I just assumed they wwere somehow blocking Linux which i didnt understand and then i did this.  I removed Networkmanager, installed connman.  Connects right up everytime, fast, with no problem.  Installed a different flavor of Ubuntu actuallky i think MXlinux 23 is debian.  Same exact problem, wont connect with networkmanager, as soon as i switch to connman, works like a charmp.  Connman is OK, but definately like as full featured as network manager.  Any idea at all what may be the difference between network manager and connman that allows connman to connect via wifi?
inxi -N   Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi

Comment: look at this question and its answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/826998/cannot-log-in-to-public-open-wifi-connection

Comment: Open a terminal and execute `inxi -N`. Copy the text from the terminal into your question. (No screenshot) Then we know your hardware and could answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you i originally thought that was the problem however I'm not able to make the connection at all.  It never gets a DHCP assignment.

Comment: Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi.  Also just to add.  I can connect to my home Wifi and other wifi's without a problem.  Thats why at first I was certain it was something with the network but as i stated connman works great.  I assume since I'm not getting a DHCP assignment, it has something to do with that.

Comment: Ok, I just did some more testing.  It has to be a DHCP problem.  For whatever reason I am not getting assigned a DHCP address.  I just fired up my verizon air card and i connected right up.  It has somethng to do with how the wifi here is handing out DHCP addresses.  Something Network manager doesnt like that Connman doesn't have an issue with.